# Laravel: Sum of foreach

Tags: php, laravel

I have this `foreach` loop:

my `$items` looks like this:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "variant_id" => "393c6c70-8cb7-11e8-815a-f9c70a1fbe8e"
    "name" => "Medicine 1"
    "quantity" => "1"
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "variant_id" => "8a80d340-e0c1-11e8-86a4-3b06d2b50e37"
    "name" => "Medicine 2"
    "quantity" => "1"
  ]
]
```

Now, in my `foreach`, I compare the `variant_id` to my database and get the `points` from that database and multiply it by the `quantity` of the Medicines.

`points` for Medicine 1 is = 50

`points` for Medicine 2 is = 20

so it should be 50(medicine 1 points) multiplied by 1 (quantity of medicine 1) and 
20 x 1 (medicine 2) and then the sum of both which should be equal to 70. But when I `dd($sum)` what I get is 50 which is only for medicine 1.

```
    $sum = 0;
    foreach ($items as $variants) {
        $id = $variants['variant_id'];
        $quantity = $variants['quantity'];
        $find = Activity::where('variant_id', $id)->first();
        $act_points = $find->points * $quantity;
        $sum += $act_points;
        dd($sum);
    }
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: `dd($sum);` __after__ `foreach`.

Comment: You have to print the data after completion of your loop. So it will gives you the correct result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can see `dd()` as a Dump and Die. This will dump the asked data and kills the script. Because this is executed, the script gets terminated before it can finish the loop

You need to use the `dd()` **after** the foreach-loop

```
$sum = 0;
foreach ($items as $variants) {
    $id = $variants['variant_id'];
    $quantity = $variants['quantity'];
    $find = Activity::where('variant_id', $id)->first();
    $act_points = $find->points * $quantity;
    $sum += $act_points;
}
dd($sum);
```

If you do not want to halt the execution of your script, use the `dump` function instead.

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-dd

Answer (score 1):

I figure out you are doing Debug dump (dd) inside foreach loop so it will just stop after the first iteration.

You should do dd outside of foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

To rationalize and avoid multiple DB calls yu can do the next

```
$input = [
    [
        "variant_id" => "393c6c70-8cb7-11e8-815a-f9c70a1fbe8e",
        "name" => "Medicine 1",
        "quantity" => "1",
    ],
    [
        "variant_id" => "8a80d340-e0c1-11e8-86a4-3b06d2b50e37",
        "name" => "Medicine 2",
        "quantity" => "1",
    ],
];

$sum = Activity::whereIn('variant_id', array_column($input, 'variant_id'))->get()->sum(function ($s) use ($input) {
    foreach ($input as $k => $v) {
        if ($s->variant_id == $v['variant_id']) {
            return $s->points * $v['quantity'];
        }
    }
});
```

This will work if in `$input` array there is no repeating elements by `variant_id`.
In other words if each `$input[n]['variant_id']` value is unique.